# Gremlin: Find all downstream (out) paths from given Vertex

Tags: java, graph, gremlin, janusgraph

I have a directed graph with around 1000 vertices and 3000 edges that contains cycles.

I am trying to find all downstream (out) paths from given Vertex.

When using following Gremlin query

```
g.V(45712).repeat(out().simplePath()).until(outE().count().is(0)).path()
```

For some paths it takes forever to get the result because of the cycles, although the `simplePath` step should prevent this.

I tried to optimize the query and not go over the same Vertex twice using `aggregate` step and `without`, but now some Vertices are being skipped.

```
g.V(45712).repeat(out().where(without('x'))
.aggregate(Scope.local,'x'))
.until(outE().count().is(0))
.path()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your data is highly connected, that can be an expensive query. Even with a small graph. I have seen people use constraints to try and restrict the total amount of searching. These could include using `times` or `loops` to set a maximum search depth. Even with my air-routes data set, which is really quite a small graph, that query could yield a very large result set. It's not so much that your Gremlin is wrong. It's more going to depend on how connected the vertices are.

Searching for all paths from a given start in general is likely to be expensive query.

Comment: Kelvin, thanks a lot for rapid answer. I do understand that this might be expensive query, but the same graph loaded into Cytoscape for example and using this not very sophisticated algorithm `https://github.com/nrnb/gsoc2012ritisha/blob/master/src/org/nrnb/pathexplorer/logic/FindAllPaths.java` can dot the same job in milliseconds. So I guess there is something wrong either with query or the engine, which is JanusGraph (Cassandra+Elastic).

Comment: To rule out a few things can you load your data into a simple in memory TinkerGraph and try it there to see if you see it working faster? How many paths should the query find? Your first query will do what you want. It's not the query - at least the query should do what you want and it is I think the typical way to try it.

Comment: I did a quick read on that java code and it doesn't seem to be doing the same as your query -- it doesn't give all paths starting from V1 -- but just runs a simple BFS (which doesn't repeat Vertices in general). The simplePath statement will ensure that return paths doesn't contain same twice. But in a highly connected graph is very likely that there will be multiple non-cyclic paths from A to B